# Making requests to NASA website using requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers

I want to download Apollo images from Nasa website using requests module in Python.

This is my beginning code-

```
>>> import requests

>>> url = "https://images.nasa.gov/search-results?q=Apollo"

>>> headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

>>> res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> res.status_code

>>> len(res.content)
>>> print(res.content)



200
2868
b'<!doctype html><!--[if IE 9]>\n\t<html class="no-js ie9" lang="en">\n<![endif]--><!--[if !IE 9]>--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" data-ng-app="availFeApp"> <!--<![endif]--> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"> <meta name="pinterest" content="nopin"> <meta name="google-site-verification" content="ZKpcXLqaBX3jND8Fybkvr3MaaOpC_6MRjXBYm0XNkJQ"> <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"> <base href="/"> <!--Title--> <meta property="og:title" content="{{ngMeta.title}}"> <title ng-bind="ngMeta.title"></title> <meta property="og:description" content="{{ngMeta.description}}"> <meta ng-if="ngMeta[\'url\']" property="og:url" content="{{ngMeta.url}}"> <meta ng-if="ngMeta[\'image\']" property="og:image" content="{{ngMeta.image}}"> <meta ng-if="ngMeta[\'imageWidth\']" property="og:image:width" content="{{ngMeta.imageWidth}}"> <meta ng-if="ngMeta[\'imageHeight\']" property="og:image:height" content="{{ngMeta.imageHeight}}"> <meta ng-if="ngMeta[\'fbAppId\']" ng-if="ngMeta[\'fbAppId\']" property="fb:app_id" content="{{ngMeta.fbAppId}}"> <meta ng-if="ngMeta[\'type\']" property="og:type" content="{{ngMeta.type}}"> <!--favicon support--> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png?v=eEa2MLRaNk"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png?v=eEa2MLRaNk" sizes="32x32"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png?v=eEa2MLRaNk" sizes="16x16"> <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json?v=eEa2MLRaNk"> <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=eEa2MLRaNk" color="#0d3d92"> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=eEa2MLRaNk"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.100c511f.css"> <!--google fonts--> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400" rel="stylesheet"> <!--pretty checkbox library styles--> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pretty-checkbox@3.0/dist/pretty-checkbox.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.8534951e.css"> <!-- We participate in the US government\'s analytics program. See the data at analytics.usa.gov. --> <script async type="text/javascript" src="https://dap.digitalgov.gov/Universal-Federated-Analytics-Min.js?agency=NASA&dclink=true" id="_fed_an_ua_tag"></script>  <body ng-strict-di> <!--[if lt IE 7]>\n\t<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>\n\t<![endif]--> <div id="page-wrapper" data-ng-view="" autoscroll="true"></div> <script src="scripts/vendor.d2e52c64.js"></script> <script src="scripts/scripts.bd45ad67.js"></script>  '
```

However, the website can detect that I am not using my browser.
I have tried with other headers also, but it does not work
What can I do to surpass this?
Please tell

Comment: They don't detect anything, what you get is the whole content of the requested page, but you don't get far w/o running all those JS scripts, which the requests module won't do for you.

Comment: So, which module can I use instead of requests?

Comment: ``Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`` see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Maybe [requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) I just bumped into this on a SO question a minute ago and don't know much about it. But it says it does javascript. Otherwise selenium, which runs through your web browser, is often used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make an HTTP GET request to `https://images.nasa.gov/search-results?q=Apollo` using the `requests` module, you get back exactly the resource you requested from the server: that HTML file. Nothing else. When you make the same request with a browser, the browser knows to parse that HTML file to execute scripts, make ajax requests / XHR requests, make requests based on meta data / links / stylesheets in the HTML, etc. It's this action by the browser that completely renders a given page the way it's meant to be seen by human eyes. When you make a simple HTTP GET request to a page, like what you're doing, you just get back the barebones template, where the DOM hasn't been populated yet, since this is typically meant to happen asynchronously at a later point in time.

You can still use the `requests` module, but you'll just use it differently: Instead of making an HTTP GET request to a webpage, you make an HTTP GET request to NASAs RESTful image asset API, which is the same API your browser makes requests to when populating the page. This is ideal because you won't have to scrape a page using BeautifulSoup or anything like that, you just imitate the same request your browser would make, and you get back JSON:

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search"

    params = {
        "q": "apollo",
        "page": "1",
        "media_type": "image",
        "year_start": "1920",
        "year_end": "2020"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()

    images = response.json()["collection"]["items"]
    for image in images:
        thumbnail_url = image["links"][0]["href"]
        image_url = thumbnail_url[:thumbnail_url.rfind("~")] + "~orig.jpg"
        print(image_url)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/APOLLO 50th_FULL COLOR_300DPI/APOLLO 50th_FULL COLOR_300DPI~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/s69-35505/s69-35505~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-35503/S69-35503~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/7995383/7995383~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-16402/S69-16402~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-34968/S69-34968~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-34969/S69-34969~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA13058/PIA13058~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA14003/PIA14003~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-60662/S69-60662~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-34313/S69-34313~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-33999/S69-33999~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-27915/S69-27915~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S68-56002/S68-56002~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/200907200097HQ/200907200097HQ~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S68-26890/S68-26890~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S68-26958/S68-26958~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S68-27041/S68-27041~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S68-27076/S68-27076~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S68-27161/S68-27161~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S68-26936/S68-26936~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-27089/S69-27089~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/200907200096HQ/200907200096HQ~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/200907200094HQ/200907200094HQ~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/200907200095HQ/200907200095HQ~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110018/NHQ201812110018~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110017/NHQ201812110017~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110027/NHQ201812110027~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-25478/S69-25478~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-25861/S69-25861~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-25862/S69-25862~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-25881/S69-25881~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0104/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0104~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/200907200098HQ/200907200098HQ~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S67-50903/S67-50903~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-19983/S69-19983~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/as17-162-24050/as17-162-24050~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110008/NHQ201812110008~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110019/NHQ201812110019~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110042/NHQ201812110042~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110009/NHQ201812110009~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110010/NHQ201812110010~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S68-26668/S68-26668~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/Maura_test_s69-36593/Maura_test_s69-36593~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-36593/S69-36593~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/200907200015HQ/200907200015HQ~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0123/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0123~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/as09-23-3596/as09-23-3596~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S67-49447/S67-49447~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-35099/S69-35099~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-26148/S69-26148~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_KLS02_0062/KSC-20190716-PH_KLS02_0062~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0063/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0063~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/jsc2007e034221/jsc2007e034221~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/9309375/9309375~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110004/NHQ201812110004~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/0102627/0102627~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/200907200091HQ/200907200091HQ~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/200907200093HQ/200907200093HQ~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110006/NHQ201812110006~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110007/NHQ201812110007~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110041/NHQ201812110041~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110034/NHQ201812110034~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110036/NHQ201812110036~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110037/NHQ201812110037~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110030/NHQ201812110030~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110040/NHQ201812110040~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110016/NHQ201812110016~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110002/NHQ201812110002~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110025/NHQ201812110025~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110035/NHQ201812110035~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110014/NHQ201812110014~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110015/NHQ201812110015~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/NHQ201812110038/NHQ201812110038~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-35507/S69-35507~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-35504/S69-35504~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S71-37963/S71-37963~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/as17-152-23272/as17-152-23272~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/0101493/0101493~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/6761216/6761216~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/6870605/6870605~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0144/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0144~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/0101140/0101140~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20170127-PH_KLS02_0005/KSC-20170127-PH_KLS02_0005~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/s69-32614/s69-32614~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/s69-34039/s69-34039~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-62224/S69-62224~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S72-50438/S72-50438~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/9309295/9309295~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/as14-67-09364/as14-67-09364~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0085/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0085~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0204/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0204~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0393/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0393~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S69-18569/S69-18569~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S66-36742/S66-36742~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/jsc2007e045377/jsc2007e045377~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0088/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0088~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0053/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0053~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0018/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0018~orig.jpg
https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0316/KSC-20190716-PH_FWM04_0316~orig.jpg
>>>
```

What I've done here is a little naive, because to get the original sized image, all I did was purge the `~thumb.jpg` at the end of each thumbnail URL, and replaced it with `~orig.jpg` - this assumes that the original has a JPEG extension. The better solution would be to look at `image["href"]`, which is a URL to another JSON file, which contains URLS for all the different versions / dimensions of a given image. You'd simply make another request to that JSON file, and then a request to one of the URLs contained within that JSON.

Answer (score 2):

We have docs for the API right in the footer of images.nasa.gov:

https://images.nasa.gov/docs/images.nasa.gov_api_docs.pdf

Check it out, you should be able to do everything with it that we do with the web application: our front-end is just Angular which talks to the API -- you can do the same thing with requests. Just connect to

https://images-api.nasa.gov/

instead of the web front-end.

The docs include examples using Curl, which you should be able to translate to requests. We use requests, ourselves, for writing utilities to manipulate the API.

Have fun!